# Default to Pages '09 when Pages '13 is also installed?

Tags: pages, iwork

Both Pages '09 and Pages '13 use "com.apple.iWork.Pages" as a bundle ID.

I can set individual .pages files to open with Pages '09, but when I try to set *all* .pages files to open with Pages '09, Pages '13 keeps taking over.†

† Selecting a .pages file, changing to "Pages '09", and then clicking "Change All…" always selects Pages '13. You can see it here https://vimeo.com/78545014.

Anyone know how to force OS X to accept Pages '09 as the default for all .pages files?

Answer (score 1):

If Pages '09 is already open, any Pages documents you double-click will open in that app, rather than in Pages '13.

To make sure Pages'09 is always open, I added it to the list of Login items (`System Preferences —> Accounts —> Login Items`).

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the new iWorks app is a new folder.
2. Open System Preferences.
3. Go to Spotlight > Privacy > Add the folder in step 1.
4. Trash the new iWorks folder.
5. Rightclick on any .pages file and click Get Info.
6. Change the open with to the pages ’09
7. put the new iWorks folder out of trash.

Warning:
When the app store updates the apps, put the new iWork applications back into the folder.

http://www.freeforum101.com/iworktipsntrick/viewtopic.php?p=698&mforum=iworktipsntrick

Answer (score -1):

Take a backup before you attempt the following.

Since the bundle identifier is currently the same, you would have to manually make them different. It's likely that iWork '09 won't get any updates, so you could change its bundle identifier like so (suffix '09' in the ID in `Contents/Info.plist` of Pages '09 under `/Applications`):

```
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.iWork.Pages09</string>
```

You would also have to rename the few preferences files under `~/Library/Preferences/` (`com.apple.iWork.Pages*.plist`), substituting `Pages` with `Pages09` in the name.

Change the application association like you have already attempted (or use [duti](https://github.com/fitterhappier/duti) to change/verify it).

Comment: Pages won't even launch if I change the CFBundleIdentifier. It will open and immediately close.

Comment: @TJLuoma You could try refreshing the code signature as well but it might not be enough